# On higher dimension, does rotation matrix product some vector match reflection matrix product the vector?

Tags: matrices, rotations, reflection

When you reflect a vector with reflection matrix on 2 dimensional space, and 3 dimensional space, intuitively we know there's rotation matrix can make same result.

But is it possible on higher dimension(4, 5, 6...)?

I know rotation matrix can be represented through reflection matrix product reflection matrix, not vice versa.

Comment: What makes you think your first statement is true?

Comment: Since I am not good at math, I can't prove it. but on 2,3-dimensional space, we can draw some pictures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have two vectors $u$ and $v$ with $|u|=|v|$, you can construct both a reflection and a rotation in any dimension that will transfer $u\to v$.

For reflection: take hyperplane with normal $u-v$.

For rotation: rotate in plane $(u,v)$ by angle $\arccos(u\cdot v)$ and by any other angles in orthogonal planes.

However, the result of this transformation will be the same only for vector $u$ because in general reflection is not the same as rotation.

Comment: I really appreciated your answer. It bugs me out for days. It was so long time I studied Linear algebra.

But, I don't understand what you said that "the result of this transformation will be the same only for vector u".

you just imply that it works for vector, but it doesn't work for matrix?